# Should there be a space after “No.”, “p. (=page)” before numbers and after “a./p.” before “m.”

Tags: punctuation

Should there be a space

- after “No.”, “p. (=page)” before numbers
- and after “a./p.” before “m.”

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't ask each in a separate question? They are not all that related and it makes people searching for an answer to either not find them so easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MLA](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_and_style_guide.html?5) and [APA](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2018/09/how-to-quote-a-foreign-language-source-and-its-translation.html), although not explicitly outlined anywhere I can find, use a space after "p."/"pp.".

"No." also is followed by a space (see the aforelinked MLA page and [here](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2018/09/how-to-cite-a-government-report-in-apa-style.html) for an example in APA).

---

There is never any space in "a.m." or "p.m.", but some style guides say to not use periods either, or to use small caps (please see the source; small caps don't work well here):

> *The Associated Press Stylebook*:
>   4 p.m.
>
> *Microsoft Manual of Style*:
>   4 P.M. (However, *Microsoft* prefers 24-hour time notations, in which 4 P.M. is 16:00.)
>
> *The Chicago Manual of Style*
>   4 p.m. (recommended)
>   Also 4 PM or 4 P.M. (with *PM* in small capitals)
>
> *Garner's Modern English Usage*:
>   4 p.m. or 4 PM (with *PM* in small capitals)
>
> *The Gregg Reference Manual*:
>   4 p.m. or 4 P.M. (with *PM* in small capitals)
>
> <sub>[A.M., P.M., a.m., p.m.: What Is the Correct Time?](https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2009/06/what-is-the-correct-time-am-pm-am-pm-am-pm-.html)</sub>